# How to formulate navbar link to its pages in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, navigation, e-commerce, menubar

I need to formulate my website navbar and need to link it to the page. This is an e-commerce site. Each and every menu have submenus. Those menus and submenus needed to be formulated as per the given table. As this is my first project, it is a bit difficult to get an idea of how to sort it out.

[image: This is my category table.]

It means, My menu needs to load as **Desktop, Laptop, Printer & Scanner**, etc. And as a submenu of the **laptop** **hp**, and **dell** needs to be loaded using that category_id and parent_id.

**This is my blade file.**

```
<div class="hs-mega-menu vmm-tfw u-header__sub-menu" aria-labelledby="basicMegaMenu">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row u-header__mega-menu-wrapper">
            <div class="col mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <span class="u-header__sub-menu-title">Desktops</span>
                <ul class="u-header__sub-menu-nav-group mb-3">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link u-header__sub-menu-nav-link" href="#" class="font-size-15 text-gray-90">HP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link u-header__sub-menu-nav-link" href="#" class="font-size-15 text-gray-90">DELL</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link u-header__sub-menu-nav-link" href="#" class="font-size-15 text-gray-90">ACER</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link u-header__sub-menu-nav-link" href="#" class="font-size-15 text-gray-90">ASUS</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller.

**HomeController**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
   
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function landing_page()
    {
        $features = Feature::get(); 
     
        $products = Product::get();
        return view ('index',compact('products', 'features'));
    }

    public function products(Request $request, $cat_name)
    {
        $category= Category::with('products')->find($cat_name);
        return view('index')->with(compact('products'));
    }
}
```

This is my **Product** table.

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('prod_name');
            $table->string('prod_brand')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('prod_description')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_item_code')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_modal')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_size')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_weight')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_height')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_manufacturer')->nullable();
            $table->float('prod_price')->nullable();
            $table->float('prod_discount')->nullable();
            $table->float('prod_quantity')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_image_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

This is my **Category** table.

```
 public function up()
    {
       Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('cat_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('cat_image_path')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
         });
    }
```

This is my **route**.

```
Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@categories')->name('index');
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop `$categories` then `$categories->products`

**in your controller**

```php
$categories= Category::with('products')->find($cat_name);
return view('index',compact('categories'));
```

**in your bldae**

```php
<div class="hs-mega-menu vmm-tfw u-header__sub-menu" aria-labelledby="basicMegaMenu">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row u-header__mega-menu-wrapper">

            @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <div class="col mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <span class="u-header__sub-menu-title">{{ $category->name }}</span>
                <ul class="u-header__sub-menu-nav-group mb-3">
                    @foreach ($category->products as $product)
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link u-header__sub-menu-nav-link" href="#" class="font-size-15 text-gray-90">{{ $product->name }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                  
                </ul>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't show anything. I added some more details in the question please have a look. And also I need to show the category and its child category, not its products'. @Kamlesh Paul

Comment: @Zeenath then u need to make a relationship for `parent` and `child`  then u can loop

Comment: Is it a correct way to create a relationship within a table?
    public function categories_id() {
        return $this->hasMany('category_id','parent_id');
    }
    public function parent_id() {
        return $this->hasMany('category_id','parent_id');
    }       @Kamlesh Paul

Comment: public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class);
    }
    
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
    }      I related parent and child using this code. Hopefully it is correct!! @Kamlesh Paul

Comment: How Nested foreach will change?@Kamlesh Paul